# Ajax with jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**In view page:**

```
<script languge="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delete').click(function(e) {;
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        mainParent=parent.parent();

        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'post',
            url: "<?= site_url('controller_Test/fnDelete') ?>",
            data: "id="+$(this).prev().text(),

            success: function() {
                mainParent.slideUp(0,function() {
                    mainParent.remove();
                });
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Controller --controller_Test**

```
function fnDelete(){
   $data['delete_me']=$_POST['id'];

    if (!empty($data['delete_me'])){
        $this->load->model('data_Model', '', TRUE);
        $this->properties->deleteRec($data['delete_me']);
        $this->output->set_output('works');
    } else {
        $this->output->set_output('dontwork');

    }
}
```

In this fnDelete should delete a row in the database. But its not deleting. but its removing that row from the view. Am using codeigniter.
Is there anything wrong with my code.?

Comment: I don't know but the semi-colon on line 3 of view page definitely doesn't belong there.

Comment: Post your HTML as well, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you've got a strange semicolon:

```
$('#delete').click(function(e) {;
```

Remove that from the end. Then, try your data like this instead:

```
data: {"id":$(this).prev().text()}
```

You may also want to handle the response within your callback, and echo out the results so you know whether the PHP succeeded, or failed.

```
success: function(results) {
  if (results == "success") {
    /* remove associated elements */
  } else {
    alert("An error occurred.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried its not working still. I don't think that its executing the function mentioned in the url.

Comment: You need to handle the results in the success-function, so you know what is coming back.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I handled the results and found the problem with my query. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In order to test you function you may want to use fiddler or you can also add an echo into your controller and an alert in you success function.  For example:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delete').click(function(e) {;    
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({ 
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(responseText) {
                alert(responseText);
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Controller --controller_Test**

```
function fnDelete(){
   $data['delete_me']=$_POST['id'];
   echo 'deleting ' . $data['delete_me']
   // ...
}
```